# Что значит "время DOS"?

Tags: время, терминология, dos

Что значит время DOS или Дата DOS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Дата и время MS-DOS - это упакованные 16-битовые значения, которые определяют месяц, день, год и время дня MS-DOS, когда файл был последний раз записан.

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы добавите, как это время вычисляется (какое начало отсчета, какие границы)

Comment: да и 2073 год смущает))

Comment: Чисто технически в чистом DOS был максимум 2107 год. Бонусом очень желательно знать в какой ФС сейчас лежит файл, т.к. тот же Fat32 хранит уже по другому.
HxD показывает сразу 6 меток времени: DOS time/date, time64_t, FILETIME, OLETIME, time_t. Надо выбирать близкую к реальности